# Bare minimum of dependencies to work with HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I need to put some files into HDFS from my client application. I am not planning to schedule a job to hadoop, just need to drop something into HDFS.

Maven dependency on hadoop-core brings a lot of stuff like jersey-core etc, which I don't need at all.

Is there any simple client library to work with HDFS without getting a full stack of hadoop dependencies? What is the minimal set of maven dependencies I can use?

Is [webhdfs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.0/webhdfs.html) the only option?

Answer (score 0):

They introduced hadoop-client which is much better then hadoop-core as a client library.